# Nested loop time complexity (big-O) for algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

I have created a simple program and I am now task to finding the time complexity (big-O). Below is the code:

```
if(B <= A) {
    ...
    for(int i = 0; i < A; i++) {
        ...
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < B; i++) {
        ...
        if(input >= 1)
            validate = true;
        else
            validate = false;


    for(int i = 0; i < B; i++) {
        ...
        for(int k = i+1; k < B; k++) {
            ...
        }
    }
    
    if(validate == true) {
        ...
        for(int i = 0; i < B; i++)
            ...
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
}
else {
    ...
}
```

This is my attempt to the problem:

```
'if' can either be 0 or 1, therefore assigned 'z'
1st 'for loop' is A
2nd 'for loop' is B
'if' inside the 2nd 'for loop' is B, since it will run n time depending on the 2nd for loop
3rd 'for loop' is B
4th 'for loop' is B, since it is nested for loop inside 3rd 'for loop'
'if' can either be 0 or 1, therefore assigned 'v'
5th 'for loop' is B
```

Therefore:

```
z + A + B + B + (B x B) + v + B
= z + A + 3B + B^2 + v
= O(B^2)
```

I am confused on how to calculate time complexity when nested loops are involve (I am new to algorithm). Is my approach partially correct, or it is completely wrong? How should I approach such a time complexity problem for such a simple algorithm?

Lastly, if one of the above nested for loop becomes a 'while' loop, what will happen to the time complexity calculation then?

Comment: Before you can determine Big-O, you need to decide what `n` and `m` is, otherwise Big-O has no meaning. Since you have 2 inputs whose value determine the complexity, you should use those, either by specifying that `n=A` and `m=B`, or by simply using `A` and `B` themselves. So, decide on that "inputs" your Big-O will use, e.g. `n, m`, or `A, B`, then **try again**.

Comment: Hint: _O(A + B²)_

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I have re-attempted the problem by switching out the n, m to A, B and re-calculating the Big-O. My big-O is O(B^2) which is different from yours. According to my lecturer, Big-O suppose to get the highest growth, in this case B^2? I have not seen an O(A + B^2) yet in my course. Aside from this, how did you find my approach to the problem though?

Comment: Was thinking about your hint. It is A+B^2 because there are two inputs variable?

Comment: That is correct. We don't know what A and B is, so it could be that *A = B⁴*.